# Pointcloud to Laserscan in Groovy

Tags: ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Upon upgrading to ROS groovy, I have found that the pointcloud_to_laserscan package no longer exists (or as far as I can tell). Has it been renamed or replaced?

I use a PointCloud2 topic to convert to a laserscan (I am not using a Kinect). This method worked in fuerte, but I am having troubles with it in Groovy... Any help is welcome!

Thanks,

-Hunter A.

---

Ok, so I built the fuerte pointcloud_to_laserscan package from the git repository supplied, and it crashes with this error:

```
allenh1@allenh1-Vostro-430:~/filter_ws/src/curvature_extraction$ rosrun nodelet nodelet manager __name:=openni_manager
[ INFO] [1370352714.338026286]: Initializing nodelet with 8 worker threads.
[ERROR] [1370352740.338951246]: Failed to load nodelet [/variance_tracker] of type [pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan]: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan with base class type nodelet::Nodelet does not exist. Declared types are  cmd_vel_mux/CmdVelMuxNodelet depth_image_proc/convert_metric depth_image_proc/disparity depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyz depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb depth_image_proc/register depthimage_to_laserscan/DepthImageToLaserScanNodelet freenect_camera/driver image_proc/crop_decimate image_proc/debayer image_proc/rectify image_view/disparity image_view/image kobuki_auto_docking/AutoDockingNodelet kobuki_bumper2pc/Bumper2PcNodelet kobuki_controller_tutorial/BumpBlinkControllerNodelet kobuki_node/KobukiNodelet kobuki_safety_controller/SafetyControllerNodelet nodelet_tutorial_math/Plus openni_camera/driver pcl/BAGReader pcl/ExtractIndices pcl/NodeletDEMUX pcl/NodeletMUX pcl/PCDReader pcl/PCDWriter pcl/PassThrough pcl/PointCloudConcatenateDataSynchronizer pcl/PointCloudConcatenateFieldsSynchronizer pcl/ProjectInliers pcl/StatisticalOutlierRemoval pcl/VoxelGrid stereo_image_proc/disparity stereo_image_proc/point_cloud stereo_image_proc/point_cloud2 turtlebot_follower/TurtlebotFollower yocs_velocity_smoother/VelocitySmootherNodelet
```

Anybody have an idea as to what is happening? Also, it is not using the Kinect or any Openni camera...

---

Nevermind! Just had to close all the ROS apps and start them again. It is working now.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64228/pointcloud-to-laserscan-in-groovy/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2013-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

pointcloud_to_laserscan was part of the turtlebot stack in Electric and Fuerte, but was removed in Groovy in favor of the much faster [depthimage_to_laserscan](http://www.ros.org/wiki/depthimage_to_laserscan).

If you're using a depth sensor (Kinect, Xtion, etc), I suggest trying depthimage_to_laserscan. If you really need to convert a PointCloud2 to a laserscan, you should be able to pull an old version of the source and build it yourself. I would try the last version that was released into fuerte: https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/tree/fuerte (check out the fuerte tag)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-06-12**:
Hi. I was thinking about using pointcloud_to_laserscan too because you can specify that you want to use data between a min height and a max height, is it possible with the new package to select data between two heights ?